# User data tracking sites like google analytics, rich relevance are blocked in Mozilla Firefox private mode

Tags: analytics, mozilla, recommendation-engine, personalization

Sites like rich relevance, google analytics which are used for creating personalized user experience by tracking user data are blocked in Mozilla Firefox private mode. On my e-commerce site, recommended products are displayed using rich relevance. Since rich relevance is blocked in Mozilla private mode, recommended products are not displayed on site.

I know it's because of content blocking feature in Mozilla Firefox private mode which blocks list of sites which have been identified as engaging in cross-site tracking of users.

I want to understand how it works and what can be the programmatic approach to fix the issue? Tech stack being `angularJs` and `Java`.

Comment: What issue do you want to 'fix'? Your question isn't very specific. Could you explain what troubles you are facing and show code that you have tried to solve them?

Comment: @drclaw I want a solution which will unblock above sites in Mozilla private mode. I have edited my problem statement.

Comment: @ChaitaliRaut while there might be ways to work around the problem, it would break the user expectation of "not being tracked" and it would probably be fragile enough to be "counter-fixed" shortly after. Your best shot is to work on user experience there: if you really need to track, just tell your users that the feature is only available outside of private mode.

Comment: @Dexter I understand what you are saying and that's what the feature is for. But because of some constraints, I want to unblock trackers in Private mode without going into setting. Thus I am asking how these domains fall under tracker category.